# Efficient way to count and find occurrences ( lotto Analysis )

Tags: java, grouping

There is two things i want to achieve :
    1) find out the pair number from lotto result and store to Hash table.
    2) loop through the lotto result in a efficient way, count the frequency and add the frequency result to pair number hash table.

I want to build a program that able to tell me the pair number frequency.

```
For a list / array of number , example :
    4, 12, 20 , 32, 48, 50
    2, 22, 20 , 32, 38, 40
    4, 12, 20 , 25, 33, 44
    1, 11, 20 , 31, 48, 50
    1, 12, 20 , 36, 47, 51
```

The result I want :

```
    Pair Number     |      Repeat Times
    4, 12                          2
    4, 20                          2
    12, 20                         3
      .                            .
      .                            .
```

list out all the possible pair number automatics
The data not necessary in list / array .
Any another recommendation to store the data for easy grouping ? map  ?

Any efficient way to group and count the repeat number other than looping ?

Appreciate for any suggestion and advice.

Comment: It's not clear what the difference between "group" and "number" is here. Is your input actually a list of lists, or just 30 numbers? Please clarify.

Comment: any pair number appear more than 1 times in a list / map / array .

Comment: i still not decide store the data in list / array / map. any recommendation ?

Comment: So these shouldn't be treated as individual numbers, but as pairs of numbers? Why didn't you even mention this to start with? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: sorry for the confusing title. ya, treated as pairs of number. Any idea ?

Comment: Actually, I'm still confused - (4, 20) doesn't even appear in your input list as a pair. Read the article I linked to and rewrite your question from scratch. I don't know whether anyone else can answer it at the moment, but I certainly can't.

Comment: the program need to wise enough to find out any pair number appear more than once in a list. The ( 4, 20  ) appear in (  first and third list )

Comment: I think whats really confusing is the fact that we have no idea what the context is, besides lotto game.

Comment: How does that pair occur? I dont see 4 and 20 ever paired in lists 1 and 3??

Comment: The pair occur not limit in the position of the list. How about if i pass in the pair number ( 4, 20 ) to a function to find the frequency ?

Comment: seem like i need to determine the pair number and pass to a function the find the frequency. Although this is not my first intention, may be it sound imppossible without knowing the pair number in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity's sake, let's say you are starting with `n` sets consisting of `c` elements (or numbers, in this case).  Your problem is to find the aggregate frequencies (that is, spanning all of the sets) of all unique subsets of size 2 of all of the sets.

To do this, loop over each set and consider every pair of elements in that set and maintain its frequency in a hash table.  When you consider a pair, if it already present in the hash table, add 1 to its value; otherwise, add it to the hash table with value 1.  Your code will resemble something vaguely similar to the pseudocode below.

```
hashtable h
for s in sets:
   for i in s.size():
       for j > i in s.size():
            pair p = (s[i],s[j])
            if h.exists(p):
                h[p]++
            else:
                h.put(p,1)
```

Since this approach has a triply nested loop with limits of `n`, `c`, and `c`, this algorithm performs in `O(nc^2)` time.

Consider an extreme case in which every possible subset of size 2 is unique.  In such a case, you table of frequencies will consist of `n × c choose 2` elements.  In big-O notation, this value reduces to `O(nc^2)`.  Therefore, the best solution is no better than `O(nc^2)`, which is precisely the speed of the algorithm described above.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. The list of lotto result store in set might not work because two different draw might have the same result.  If there is no pair number predefined in the first place, how to find  the pair number from a given list of lotto ?

Comment: @JasonHue If a lotto pick can contain duplicate values, use a list instead of a set.  The logic is otherwise identical.

Comment: how about to find the pair number from a given list of lotto ?  pair number base on the draw result instead of predefined .

Comment: @JasonHue That is what the inner part of the loop does: `for i in s.size(), for j > i in s.size() ...`.  Here, `j` and `i` correspond to elements in each possible pair.

Comment: the hashmap to store the pair number will be like this

Comment: @JasonHue I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.  I hope my answer serves in some way to assist your problem.

Comment: the hashmap to store the pair number will be like this            Map<Map<object[], String>, int> map = new HashMap<Map<object[], String>,int >();  correct ?  The inner hashmap store the pair number, string store the description and the int store the frequency value.